# Stop browser forcing form element into window view

Tags: browser, focus, field

Any ideas how to stop browsers from forcing focused form fields into view when positioned overflow hidden?

Answer (score 0):

How about moving the offending field off the page (position:absolute;top:-9999;)? That will take it out of view.

If you're wanting the field to appear where you originally put it however you could have a dummy set of fields (taken off the page with top:-9999) and transfer focus to them as the user goes through the form. If you update the fields in view as the dummy fields are changed then you can give the impression the user is manipulating the visible form.